# Windows 7, SandyBridge -> IvyBridge update, windows won't start or install

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, boot, sandy-bridge, ivy-bridge

I'm having trouble trying to replace an Intel Pentium G630 (2.7 GHz) CPU with an Intel Core i5-3570. The rest of my system is as follows:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Motherboard: MSI B75MA-45P
- BIOS 1.10 updated to 1.50 via LiveUpdate 5 (from the motherboard's install disk).

The old (Pentium G630) CPU works as it should, but the new (Core i5) CPU:

- causes Windows to show the logo, but right before it should show the desktop, the computer restarts.
- Safe mode checks files/drivers, but right before it should show the desktop, the computer restarts.
- Installation shows the logo, then computer restarts

Any idea why this happens and what a possible solution may be?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be with CPU fan not connected properly. Check for both the processor fan and the chassis fans are working.